# Issue working with double pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I'm new to C and having trouble wrapping my head around double pointers and keep getting segmentation fault errors. I've debugged the program a bit and located where things go wrong, but can't for the life of me figure out why. I'll post my code first:

```
int main() { 
    printf("Enter string to be split: \n");
    a = readline();
    String *st = newString(a);
    String **split;
    int num;
    num = string_split(st, ',', split);
    for (i=0; i<num; i++) { print_string(*(split+i)); }
}
```

readline() produces a pointer to an array of chars (entered by the user) and appends '\0' to it. newString and print_string definitely work. Here's the struct for string:

```
typedef struct {
    char *chars;
    int length;
    int maxSize;
} String;
```

And here is the code for string_split which is causing me all this trouble.

```
int string_split(String *s, char delim, String **arrayOfStructs) {
    char *c = getCharacters(s);
    int len = length(s);
    int begin = 0;
    int end;

    int arraycount = 0;
    String **temp = (String**)malloc(sizeof(String*));

    for (end=0; end<len+1; end++) {
        if ((*(c+end) == delim || *(c+end) == '\0') && begin != end) {
            String *st = substring(s,begin,end-1);
            *(temp + arraycount) = st;
            begin = end + 1;
            arraycount++;
            temp = (String**)realloc(temp, 1+arraycount*sizeof(String*));
        }
    }

    arrayOfStructs = temp;
    return arraycount;
}
```

In main, when I get back split, all the String*'s that it points too are gone. When print_string gets an individual String* and tries to grab one of its members, a segmentation fault occurs. I don't understand why, because I feel like I allocate memory every time it is necessary, but I feel like I'm missing something. Also, when debugging, if I step through string_split, temp is produced exactly like I expect, so I think I'm just not malloc'ing somewhere where I'm supposed to and it's not a problem with the logic of the function. Here is the code in substring, although I'm pretty sure it works since I've been able to return String* from substring and pass them to print_string just fine.

```
String *substring(String *s1, int begin, int end) {
    String *s = (String*)malloc(sizeof(String));
    int length = 0;
    s->maxSize = 20;
    char *temp = (char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    char *arr = s1->chars;

    int i;
    for (i=begin; i <= end; i++) {
        *(temp+length) = *(arr+i);
        length++;

        if (length == s1->maxSize-1) {
            s1->maxSize = s1->maxSize+20;
            temp = (char*)realloc(temp, s1->maxSize*sizeof(char));
        }
    }
    *(temp+length) = '\0';
    s->length = length;
    s->chars = temp;    
    return s;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the argument `arrayOfStructs` *by reference* and not by value. As C doesn't actually have proper references, you have to pass a pointer to the variable:

```
int string_split(String *s, char delim, String ***arrayOfStructs) {
    ...

    *arrayOfStructs = temp;
    return arraycount;
}
```

Call it using the address-of operator `&`:

```
num = string_split(st, ',', &split);
```

---

As it is now, you pass the argument *by value*, which means that the variable `arrayOfStructs` is just a local copy inside the function. Any changes to it is only made to the copy, and are lost once the variable goes out of scope when the function returns.

Comment: Ahhhhh okay that makes sense to me. If I wanted to keep it as a double pointer in the function parameter, what could I do? If I malloced split in main would that do the trick?

Comment: @user3344699 Yes, allocating outside of the function would work, but then you have no way or reallocating it in the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
  String **temp = (String**)malloc(sizeof(String*));

  *(temp + arraycount) = st;
```

temp+arraycount is going to give you a random address in memory. temp contains the pointer you just malloced, which should point to another pointer.(which you have not initialised), but you are incrementing the pointer so you loose the location you just malloced.

temp is not pointing to consecutive memory, it specifically points to another pointer(which is 8bytes on a 64bit machine)

Comment: Hmmm...so should I malloc (temp+arraycount) instead each time I want to say *(temp+arraycount)=st? And just declare String **temp; earlier? And then I would not need to realloc temp?

Comment: @user3344699 you cannot increment temp. yes you should malloc *temp = malloc(size you want).you can only increment like this *(*temp)+arraycount) after you have allocated the space of course.

Comment: I very well could be wrong since I'm new to C, but I was able to incrememnt temp like you were saying I couldn't. I implemented Joachim Pileborg's suggestion and everything worked.